# Simple FEniCS problem shape mismatch

Tags: pde, fenics

This [**presentation by the Imperial College**](http://fenicsproject.org/pub/workshops/fenics12/slides/Ham.pdf) in London has a nice example in it, on page 8, Burgers Equations. The first part of their code reads like this:

```
from dolfin import*

n = 30
mesh = UnitInterval(n)
V = FunctionSpace(mesh, "CG",2)
ic = project(Expression("sin(2*pi*x[0])"), V)
u = Function(ic)
u_next = Function(V)
v= TestFunction(V)
nu = Constant(0.0001)
timestep = Constant(1.0/n)

F1 = ((u_next - u)/timestep*v)*dx
F2 = (u_next*grad(u_next)*v)*dx
F3 = (nu*grad(v)*grad(u_next))*dx
```

On my system, this code fails, giving shape mismatch errors for the sums `F2` and `F3`. I don't understand why.

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct equation? u grad(u) = 0? That's a vector-valued equation for a scalar variable.

Comment: sorry, I'm being really sloppy here. what I mean is $\vec{u} ( \nabla \cdot \vec{u}) = 0$. I'll adjust it.

Comment: @AndersLogg ok, I realize that this doesn't make too much sense. I need to put more thought into it.

Comment: Read UFL manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem is that FEniCS doesn't recognize that in 1D, `u` and `grad(u)` have the same shape. (You could file an issue about this on the [Dolfin issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/fenics-project/dolfin/issues).)

If you replace `grad` by `div`, your code works. (The general form of the inviscid Burgers equation is $\mathop{\mathrm{div}}(u^2) = f$.)

Comment: I guess this is not issue. `u` is rank `0`, shape `()` but `grad(u)` is rank `1`, shape `(1,)`. This is consistent and is consistetly solved by using `div(u)` instead of `grad(u)`.

Comment: On the other hand `F3 = (nu*dot(grad(v), grad(u_next)))*dx` is valid in arbitrary dimension.

Answer (score 3):

If your domain is one dimensional you should use:

```
mesh = UnitIntervalMesh(10)
```

For partial derivative in x direction use:

```
u.dx(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the line

```
a = inner(inner(nabla_grad(u),u),v)*dx
```

Here you take the inner product between the vector nabla_grad(u) and the scalar u. That does not make sense.

Comment: ok, so how would I tell fenics to take the derivative with respect to x instead of the gradient?, i.e. a = (d/dx u)*u*v*dx ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the tips and hints. So after some dist-upgrading, debugging, manual reading, I finally got this script running. I'm including my solution here, just for the sake of completeness. Note that this code models the [inviscid Burgers equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation) in one dimension.

```
from dolfin import*

n = 100
mesh = UnitIntervalMesh(n)
#mesh = IntervalMesh(500,-1.,10.)
V = FunctionSpace(mesh,'CG',1)
u = Function(V)
u0 = Expression("1./(sqrt(2*pi)*0.1) * exp(-0.5*pow((x[0]-0.5),2)/0.01)")
u.interpolate(u0)

u_next = Function(V)
v = TestFunction(V)

nu = Constant(0.01)
timestep = Constant(0.01)

F = ((u_next-u)/timestep*v
     + inner(u_next.dx(0)*u_next, v))*dx
bc = DirichletBC(V, 0.0, "on_boundary")

t = 0.0
end =10
while(t <= end):
    solve(F==0, u_next, bc)
    u.assign(u_next)
    t+=float(timestep)
    plot(u)
interactive()
```